# Need to write a formula in excel to return only unique values inside of an index match formula

Tags: excel

I have a formula but it does not work.

I Have a long (1m rows) list of Company names(the list is mixed, meaning names repeat along the list). Also got a list of products (they also repeat along the list). Column 1 - company name , column 2 - product name. (products listed according to companies that have that products)
The task:
On the other worksheet, I have a drop down list of unique distinct company names.

I need to:

1. Select a company name from the list
2. the list of distinct and unique product names list(the product that that company has) to drop below

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Combined_2.0!$B$2:$B$1048575; MATCH(Sheet2!B1,COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B1:Sheet2!B1,Combined_2.0!$B$2:B1048575 )), 0)),"")` but it does not work

Comment: Make a copy of the column with the names in and then use "remove Duplicates". Or you can try the unique() function.

Comment: I have tried unique function. no luck. Remove duplicates also do not apply as i need it to be done automatically(inside the formula)

Answer (score 0):

The formula you're trying to use is an array formula, so please make sure that you're pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works correctly.

I think the UNIQUE function would work perfectly in your case but if you want to use array formulas I suggest to do the following:

1. Use a helper a column to extract the unique companies (using the formula that you have but as an array formula) and save this new information as a dynamic named range. You an create a named range and use this formula (I'm considering that the new data is in the column D):

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$1,1,0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$100,"?*")-1)

Now you can create a data validation drop down just calling the named range as a list.

2. Use another helper column to extract the unique products taking the company selected on the drop down list as an input.
3. Do the same of the step 1 to create a data validation drop down list for the unique products by company.

Check it out this example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq16RDdRfLIWIxDSDHTEYbWj_jPmlJi1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I tired your method, but maybe im just dumb or something, I could not make it work.

Comment: I have a list of mixed companies. and a list of mixed products(which company has which product). I need a drop down list of companies. As i select one, the list of its product should appear below. Pls suggest the easiest method. But it should be automated as much as possible as its impossible to process 1m rows in several steps

Comment: Could you edit your query including an example of your data? That would be helpful for an accurate answer.